# Using collection of objects in LINQ to Entities which are not modeled

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm writing a query using Linq to Entities and Entity Framework. My app uses two databases. Cross database is not an option due to client demands.

Lets say `MyEntity` resides in first database (so it is on one EF Model) and it references an entity in the second database `SecondDBEntity` (so it is on another EF Model), which has a composite key. Now, lets say I want to retrieve all `MyEntity` which references a set of `SecondDBEntity` (In our example, entities with key [1, 1], [1, 2] and [1, 3]).

The SQL I want to generate is this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM MyEntity
 WHERE (MyEntity.ForeignKeyOne = 1 AND MyEntity.ForeignKeyTwo = 1)
    OR (MyEntity.ForeignKeyOne = 1 AND MyEntity.ForeignKeyTwo = 2)
    OR (MyEntity.ForeignKeyOne = 1 AND MyEntity.ForeignKeyTwo = 3)
```

I have then tried the following code:

```
var setOfEntitiesToSearch = LetsAssumeThisIsAnIEnumerableOfSecondDBEntity;
return (from myEntity in DataContext.MyEntityList
       where setOfEntitiesToSearch.Any(entityToSearch => entityToSearch.KeyOne == myEntity.ForeignKeyOne && entityToSearch.KeyTwo == myEntity.ForeignKeyTwo)
      select myEntity).ToList();
```

This code compiles fine, but when I execute, it gives me the error:

```
"Unable to create a constant value of type 'SecondDBEntity'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."
```

My main problem is because entities are in different databases. I'm probably doing something silly, because this is a farely common query I'm trying to build. So, I believe I'm missing some feature in EF which will allow me to create this query. Maybe some CompositeKey structure? Or some way to mix those EF Models?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq can't translate the setOfEntitiesToSearch into a sql query.  It can only use primative types.  Note, an IEnumerable is not the same as an enum.  Linq can use an enum because it can be translated to a value of type integer, but it can't translate an IEnumerable into a primative type.

From what I can think of, you could go about this two different ways. (Note, I'm typing this code without compiling, so it may need debugged.)

1) Loop through setOfEntitiesToSearch and build a List like this:

```
List<MyEntity> results = new List<MyEntity>();
foreach (item in setOfEntitiesToSearch) {
    results.AddRange(
        from myEntity in DataContext.MyEntityList           
        where myEntity.ForeignKeyOne == item.KeyOne && myEntity.ForeignKeyTwo == item.KeyTwo
        select myEntity).ToList()
    );
}
return results;
```

2) Get all DataContext.MyEntityList into an in-memory list and query it.

```
var entityList = DataContext.MyEntityList.ToList()
return entityList.Where(myEntity => setOfEntitiesToSearch.Any(entityToSearch => entityToSearch.KeyOne == myEntity.ForeignKeyOne && entityToSearch.KeyTwo == myEntity.ForeignKeyTwo)).ToList()
```

Drawback to #1 - calling the db in a loop.

Drawback to #2 - entityList may be very large depending on the number of items DataContext.MyEntityList returns.

Comment: Well Aaron, for now I'm already using your first suggestion. I want to avoid it because my application MUST have a high performance, and I'm afraid any of these solutions might impact on performance. I've edited my question because it was missing the last paragraph. I truly believe it might have a better solution, maybe towards defining some Key Structure, or mixing up my two EF Models? If it cannot be done like that, then I'll mark your post as a solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, I went on and use your second suggestion. In-memory search is fast enough in my application. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

first create two lists

```
var listKeyOne = setOfEntitiesToSearch.Select(e => e.KeyOne);
var listKeyTwo = setOfEntitiesToSearch.Select(e => e.KeyTwo);
```

then use those lists like

```
return (from myEntity in DataContext.MyEntityList
       where listKeyOne.Any(keyOne => myEntity.ForeignKeyOne == keyOne) &&
             listKeyTwo.Any(keyTwo => myEntity.ForeignKeyTwo == keyTwo)
      select myEntity).ToList();
```

this makes the problem more trivial. please let me know if it works

Comment: I think this solution won't work. Because it must match the SAME index in listKeyOne AND listKeyTwo. The code you suggest is equivalent to:
`WHERE myEntity.ForeignKeyOne IN (1, 1, 1) AND myEntity.ForeignKeyTwo IN (1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: yes i misunderstood where logic, but i intentionally used IEnumerable<int> because querty interpreter thinks SecondDbEntity is part of your model